# PHP.ini change not reflected

Tags: 12.04, apache2, php, debugging, zabbix

I am trying to install Zabbix and the following errors appeared during pre-installation

[image]

I proceeded to change the setting in PHP.ini file to the minimum requirements

[image]
[image]

The problem is that though i have made the changes to the PHP.ini file , it is not being reflected and I am still getting the error. I have tried restarting the apache server but the changes are not reflected

Answer (score 4):

Lines starting with `;` are comments, used for examples and explanations. You need to add the "actual" entries, for example

```
date.timezone = "Asia/Tokyo"
```

instead of

```
;date.timezone = "Asia/Tokyo"
```

I'd recommend to *add* your entries instead of *editing* the existing, out-commented entries. So you can go back to the default just by deleting your own additions.

Additionally, there may be multiple `php.ini` files. You need to check which one is used. It mostly depends on the method you chose to integrate PHP with your webserver (probably Apache http server). If you're using the mod_php module, you need to look for `php.ini` in a subdirectory "apache2". Other subdirectories for other integration methods may be "cgi" (CGI), "cli" (PHP on the command line), "fpm" (php-fpm) and others.

You can see which `php.ini` is used in the output of PHP's `phpinfo()` function.

Comment: which line in the output of phpinfo() can i see which php.ini is used ??

Comment: Should be the 5th trough 8th line. There you'll find
- "Configuration File (php.ini) Path" (the directory the php.ini is in)
- "Loaded Configuration File " (the path to the php.ini itself)
- "Scan this dir for additional .ini files" (the directory that's, well, scanned for additional ini-files)
- "Additional .ini files parsed" (the additional ini-files that have been parsed)

Answer (score 0):

Lines starting with semicolon (;) are ignored in php.ini file. Just delete this character if You want to activate a directive.